# div box with in a div box when placing text it pushes all boxes out

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a page with using bootstrap container and rows which for the best part works ok. some of the columns have CSS circles to use as gauges.

I have  problem with the last column of a row which when I add div boxes with in the panel div I have made and then adding text to the div's it pushes all the other columns to increase there sizes.

With out the text and just the divs it is all ok. I can't work out a way to stop this

This is a screen shot with no text added as you can see the gauge looks ok
[image: without Text]

[image: with text]

This is the code

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  margin: 1% 1% 1% 0%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: black;
  background-size: cover;
}

.panel {
  margin: 0% 0% 85% 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.weatherpanel {
  margin: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.gaugeTitle {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.outerGauge {
  margin: 10% 0% 0% 13%;
  /*top right bottom left */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px red;
  position: absolute;
}

.innerGauge {
  margin: 8% 0% 0% 7%;
  /*top right bottom left */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 85%;
  height: 85%;
  background: green;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 4px green;
  position: absolute;
}

.gaugeText {
  margin-top: -5%;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 7vw;
}

.stocks {
  margin: auto;
  height: 10%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2vw;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="weatherpanel">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel">
              <div class="gaugeTitle" id="wateTitle"></div>
              <div class="outerGauge">
                <div class="innerGauge" id="water">
                  <div class="gaugeText" id="waterGauge">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="panel">
              <div class="stocks" id="TCG">text</div>
              <div class="stocks" id="AA">text</div>
              <div class="stocks" id="ABF">text</div>
              <div class="stocks" id="STOB">text</div>
              <div class="stocks" id="MCLS">text</div>
              <div class="stocks" id="BA">text</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="newindex.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Below links is a test server with the test page without text

http://motorhomertestsite.ddns.net/newIndex.html

and the next link with text added

http://motorhomertestsite.ddns.net/withText.html

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by removing the 85% margin from panel class. Which works on this part but means I will need to create a new class for the rest of the page which was using this class

```
.panel {
  margin: 0% 0% 85% 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You can move all the matching elements to a super class and then the margin attributes to specific classes. Then just add both the super class and specific class to the HTML element. Makes your CSS DRY-er.

Comment: just did this and it has tidied it up nicely thanks